# how i update an app with my data connection in letv1s

Tags: google-play-store

I want to update apps with data connection in letv1s  they are waited for wifi but i want to update apps through my data connection

Answer (score 1):

Open Google Play, then open the drawer. Tap on **Settings** > **Auto-update apps**. Set it to **Auto-update apps at anytime. Data charges may apply**

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>